# Selecting geographic points within a bounding box using SQLite and PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, google-maps-api-3, geospatial, postgis

I'm writing a PHP/SQLite backend API that needs to return all points within a geographic bounding box. This will be used to retrieve markers within the visible area of a Google Map via an AJAX call.

It's one of those things that sound super easy to do at first, just do a

```
SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat <= :maxLat AND lat >= :minLat 
    AND lng <= :maxLng AND lng >= :minLng;
```

But suppose the bounding box is

```
minLat = 13
maxLat = 14
minLng = -178
maxLng = 179
```

i.e. across the -180/180 degree longitude. Now the above query will instead select points outside the bounding box!

How can I solve this using SQLite and PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I think I got it.

I ended up creating a different query depending on if `south` is larger than `north` for latitudes and/or `west` is larger than `east` for longitudes, combining them so that there are a total of 4 possible queries.

```
// $coords = ['lngW'=>179, 'lngE'=>-178, 'latS'=>13, 'latN'=>14];

$whereLng = $coords['lngE'] < $coords['lngW'] ? 
  '(lng >= :lngW OR lng <= :lngE)' : 
  '(lng >= :lngW AND lng <= :lngE)';

$whereLat = $coords['latN'] < $coords['latS'] ? 
  '(lat >= :latS OR lat <= :latN)' : 
  '(lat >= :latS AND lat <= :latN)';

$getStmt = $this->db->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM places WHERE $whereLng AND $whereLat"
);

if( $getStmt->execute($coords) ){
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, the desired data in the database is not contained within a single rectangle, but in two.

Your code has to detect this case (`minLng` > `maxLng`) and change the query accordingly.

Comment: Did just that, posted a full answer.